# Shortcut to quickly kill an app

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, task-management

I have Android 4.4.2, it's rooted.

There are some apps that I execute and don't shutdown and I have to kill them. I use GO TaskManager EX widget to get rid of them, but that requires me open its dialog, look for the app icon and click it to have it killed.

Is there an app or some command I can add to a shortcut, so that I just click its icon and that app is killed in case it's opened?

Answer (score 3):

I have always felt the need for this and been using in KitKat and Marshmallow.

Since your device is rooted, it's easy. Install [Gravity Box](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-5-tweak-box-android-t2554049) Xposed module and under *Navigation bar tweaks → Custom key settings → Long press action (Kill foreground app)*  and choose your *Icon Style/Set custom image* for the icon to sit always on your Navigation Bar. Simply press it to get rid of the unresponsive app

You see the icon on extreme left, below Yahoo mail

[image]

Comment: It is configured for additional function of " screen shot" also- single tap for "screen shot" and long press for "kill foreground app".  Module has tons of other tweaks- you won't regret trying out

Comment: How did it go ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using greenify (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en). This is an app that allows you to kill any background apps automatically (it has increased functionality if you have root).

In order to set it up the way you mentioned, first go to the 3 dot selection on the top right corner on the app. Then click settings. Now click working mode and switch it to either root or boost (if you have [xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)). Finally, go back to the homescreen and click the + icon, where you can select the apps you want to hibernate.

> Is there an app or some command I can add to a shortcut, so that I
>   just click its icon and that app is killed in case it's opened?

You can do this by setting a widget with greenify. Go to your widgets (tap and hold then tap widgets for google now launcher) and select the hibernate now widget. This way you can hibernate your apps manually as well as automatically.